# Timers to measure latency

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, latency

When measuring network latency (time ack received - time msg sent) in any protocol over TCP, what timer would you recommend to use and why? What resolution does it have? What are other advantages/disadvantages?

Optional: how does it work?

Optional: what timer would you NOT use and why?

I'm looking mostly for Windows / C++ solutions, but if you'd like to comment on other systems, feel free to do so.

(Currently we use GetTickCount(), but it's not a very accurate timer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a copy of my answer from: [C++ Timer function to provide time in nano seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds#275231)

For Linux (and BSD) you want to use [clock_gettime()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock_gettime.html).

```
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
   timespec ts;
   // clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts); // Works on FreeBSD
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts); // Works on Linux
}
```

For windows you want to use the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338). And here is more on [QPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979201.aspx)

Apparently there is a known [issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274323) with QPC on some chipsets, so you may want to make sure you do not have those chipset. Additionally some dual core AMDs may also cause a [problem](http://forum.beyond3d.com/showthread.php?t=47951). See the second post by sebbbi, where he states:

> QueryPerformanceCounter() and
>   QueryPerformanceFrequency() offer a
>   bit better resolution, but have
>   different issues. For example in
>   Windows XP, all AMD Athlon X2 dual
>   core CPUs return the PC of either of
>   the cores "randomly" (the PC sometimes
>   jumps a bit backwards), unless you
>   specially install AMD dual core driver
>   package to fix the issue. We haven't
>   noticed any other dual+ core CPUs
>   having similar issues (p4 dual, p4 ht,
>   core2 dual, core2 quad, phenom quad).

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you use GetTickCount(), so I'm going to recommend that you take a look at QueryPerformanceCounter().

Answer (score 0):

There is really no substitute for the rdtsc instruction. You cannot be sure of what resolution the QueryPerformanceCounter will support. Some have a very large granularity (low increment rate/frequency), some return nothing at all.

Instead, I recommend you use the rdtsc instruction. It does not require any OS implementation and returns the number of CPU internal clock cycles that have elapsed since the computer/processor/core was powered up. For a 3 GHz processor that's 3 billion increments per second - it doesn't get more precise than that, now does it? This instruction is available for x86-32 and -64 beginning with the Pentium or Pentium MMX. It should therefore be accessible from x86 Linuxes as well.

There are plenty of posts about it here on stackoverflow.com. I've written a few myself ...