# Can measure the time passed in milli seconds? Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, time

```
time_t start = time(0);
double seconds = difftime( time(0), start);
cout <<"Seconds =" <<seconds<<endl;
```

The above code generate result in seconds (1,2, 3, 4...). It is possible to generate in 0.1 seconds or 0.01seconds?

Comment: C++11 Chrono library, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono, and specifically high_resolution_clock, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock. Timepoint, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point, has a good example of how to use the clock to time something.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307596/time-difference-in-c