# How to elegantly create a function which returns a lambda's return value or nothing?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, kotlin, return-type

I want to write a higher order function in Java which takes a lambda and returns the labmda's return value or does not return anything if the lambda has no return type.

In **Kotlin**, I would do something like this:

```
fun <T> test(block: () -> T): T {
    val r = block()
    // ...
    return r
}
```

Since `Unit` will be `T` in case *nothing* is returned, this will work.

In **Java** I could only come up with this:

```
public class Main {

    private static <T> T test(Supplier<T> s) {
        T t = s.get();
        // ...
        return t;
    }

    private static void test(Runnable r) {
        // ...
        r.run();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test(() -> System.out.println("Hello")); // returns void
        test(() -> 5); // return an Int
    }
}
```

I had to overload `test` giving it a `Supplier<T>` when I want to return the lambda's return value and a `Runnable` if the lambda does not return anything.

Is there a better way without overloading?

Since `void` (but `Void` could) cannot take the place of `T`, I don't see how.

Comment: "Is there a better way without overloading?" Does there need to be a better way?

Comment: @AndyTurner I made a comparison with how concise it is in Kotlin. So, in short: yes, it would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way without overloading?

No.

The best you can do is to avoid duplication in the overloads, by calling the `Supplier` overload from the `Runnable` overload:

```
private static void test(Runnable r) {
  test(() -> { r.run(); return null; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accept a Supplier and provide another method to wrap Runnable:

```
Supplier<?> wrap(Runnable r) {
    return () -> {
        r.run();
        return null;
    };
}
```