# How to determine your programs runtime?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer

I have to write a divide-and-conquer program to solve the following problem. Let A[1..n] and B[1..n] be two arrays of distinct integers, each sorted in an increasing order.Find the nth smallest of the 2n combined elements. I can not merge the two arrays. My program must be in  O(log n) time.

I have written my program but have no clue how to determine if it meets the requirement of the run time.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // this section of code will require user input to have the value of n to be set
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(("What number would you like to set n equal to : "));
    int value = sc.nextInt();

    // this section of code set the two array only to hold the value of n
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> setA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        int picks = rand.nextInt(1000);
        setA.add(picks);
    }
    Collections.sort(setA);
    System.out.println("A1: "+ setA);


    ArrayList<Integer> setX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int k = 0; k < value; k++) {
        int picks = rand.nextInt(1000);
        setX.add(picks);
    }
    Collections.sort(setX);
    System.out.println("A2: "+ setX);

    ArrayList<Integer> afinal = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int r = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int q = 0;
    while(afinal.size()!=  value) {
        if(setA.get(r) < setX.get(f)) {
            q = setA.get(r);
            afinal.add(q);
            r++;
        }else {
            q = setX.get(f);
            afinal.add(q);
            f++;
        }
    
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(afinal);
    int w = value - 1;
    int ans = afinal.get(w);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The nth smallest integer is "+ ans);
}
}
```

Comment: Time it...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572868/how-to-time-java-program-execution-speed

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate runtime with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

What we want to do is get the current time before the program runs, then get the time after the program runs. We then handle the two times accordingly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // this section of code will require user input to have the value of n to be set
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(("What number would you like to set n equal to : "));
    int value = sc.nextInt();

    // this section of code set the two array only to hold the value of n
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> setA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        int picks = rand.nextInt(1000);
        setA.add(picks);
    }
    Collections.sort(setA);
    System.out.println("A1: "+ setA);


    ArrayList<Integer> setX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int k = 0; k < value; k++) {
        int picks = rand.nextInt(1000);
        setX.add(picks);
    }
    Collections.sort(setX);
    System.out.println("A2: "+ setX);

    ArrayList<Integer> afinal = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int r = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int q = 0;
    while(afinal.size()!=  value) {
        if(setA.get(r) < setX.get(f)) {
            q = setA.get(r);
            afinal.add(q);
            r++;
        }else {
            q = setX.get(f);
            afinal.add(q);
            f++;
        }
    
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(afinal);
    int w = value - 1;
    int ans = afinal.get(w);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The nth smallest integer is "+ ans);
    long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
}
```

In the example above, we've got the two times. Now what do we do?

We can subtract them to get the difference in times (by milliseconds).

Like so:

```
long ellapsedMilliseconds = after-before;
```

If you want to get the elapsed time in seconds, divided `ellapsedMilliseconds` by 100.

So the final code should be;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // this section of code will require user input to have the value of n to be set
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(("What number would you like to set n equal to : "));
    int value = sc.nextInt();

    // this section of code set the two array only to hold the value of n
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> setA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        int picks = rand.nextInt(1000);
        setA.add(picks);
    }
    Collections.sort(setA);
    System.out.println("A1: "+ setA);


    ArrayList<Integer> setX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int k = 0; k < value; k++) {
        int picks = rand.nextInt(1000);
        setX.add(picks);
    }
    Collections.sort(setX);
    System.out.println("A2: "+ setX);

    ArrayList<Integer> afinal = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int r = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int q = 0;
    while(afinal.size()!=  value) {
        if(setA.get(r) < setX.get(f)) {
            q = setA.get(r);
            afinal.add(q);
            r++;
        }else {
            q = setX.get(f);
            afinal.add(q);
            f++;
        }
    
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(afinal);
    int w = value - 1;
    int ans = afinal.get(w);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The nth smallest integer is "+ ans);
    long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ellapsedMilliseconds = after-before;
    System.out.println("Execution time: "+elapsedMilliseconds);
}
}
```