# Problem with System.nanoTime()

Tags: java

I´m working on a 2d java game but I´m stuck on timer problems. Here is my game loop:

```
void gameLoop(isRunning){
....

doStuff();

....
}
```

I have a fps measuring code like this inside the loop:

```
long thisLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
delta = thisLoop - lastLoopTime;
lastLoopTime = thisLoop;
```

So I get how much time has passed since last loop. However, whenever I try to use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System,currentTimeMillis()` like this:

```
long thisLoop = System.nanoTime();
delta = thisLoop - lastLoopTime;
lastLoopTime = thisLoop;
```

My game gets completely screwed, doesn't render anything past first frame, no errors reported just frozen. I´m on win 7 64 lastest java 1.6. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you doing anything with `delta` or `lastLoopTime`? That's probably where the problem is, but you haven't posted that code.

Comment: What OS & version? See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588605).

Answer (score 5):

Try using `System.nanoTime() / 1000000` since it's in nanoseconds instead of milliseconds like you're probably expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Are you multiplying or dividing by 1,000,000? [1 millisecond = 1 000 000 nanoseconds](http://www.google.com/search?q=1%20ms%20in%20ns). I'm assuming that the rest of your logic is implemented in terms of milliseconds.

Comment: Pretty sure there are 1,000,000 nanoseconds in a millisecond :)

Comment: AHAHAHAHAHAH! I'm so tired right now my eyeballs hurt. But maybe that's the problem in the code?!!!

Comment: Hehe, I like you how linked the conversion to Google now.