# How do I get accurate timestamps for job execution durations in a multithreaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading

How to add timestamp into a multi threaded program where I have:

- J3 dependent on J1 & J2
- J5 dependent on J4

And get the different times of executions of each job (thread).
I have 6 different files of J1, J2, J3 (where I have joined J1 & J2), J4, J5 (where I have joined J4) and J6 (where I start all the threads).

I have added this function:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:ms");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Sample Code(of one thread) --

```
import java.io.*;
import java.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Job1 extends Thread{
String msg;
public void run()
{


System.out.println("Execution of job1 (addition job) started");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("3+2=" +(3+2));
System.out.println();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:ms");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     }

     Job1(String mg)
     {
      msg=mg;
     }

     }
```

But, I am getting the same time for every thread.

**Update**

This is the output I am getting.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin>javac threadcontainer.java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin>java threadcontainer
J1->4719906194666
J2->4719906696464
Execution of job1 (addition job) started
3+2=5
J4->4719911159535
Execution of job4 (multiplication job) started
3*2=6Job 5 executing
J5-> 4719911737462
Execution of job2 (subtraction job) started
3-2=1Job 3 executing
J3->4719912405874
```

Comment: Could you please post more code ?

Comment: Are you using the same `SimpleDateFormat` across all threads?

Comment: yeah. the same Date format code

Comment: jdk dateformats are not threadsafe

Comment: I suspect the OP is creating a new SimpleDateformat every time it is used. In this case there is no thread safety issue. (But the performance is not very good either)

Comment: So what the complain ? The program is too fast and so Date havent changed by the time all is finished ? or do you suspect a bug?

Comment: Don't post additional info in answers. Edit your question instead. Stackoverflow is not a forum.

Answer (score 4):

You should use System.nanoTime() is much more accurate and much faster.

---

Calendar is one of the most expensive objects you can create and using a date format is likely to be very inefficient.  The ":ms" doesn't do anything useful, so I suspect you only have second resolution.  If you want milli-seconds use ".SSS" as per the javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

First, post more code, so that we can see what you are really doing and what you to with the date format and so on.

And then: Javadoc for SimpleDateFormat says:

> Synchronization
>
> SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe.
>   Users should create a separate
>   instance for each thread.

Which may cause what you see.

Comment: Sample thread- \npublic class Job1 extends Thread{ String msg; public void run() { /*DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:ms"); Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance)System.out.println("Job1---" +dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); */ System.out.println("Execution of job1 (addition job) started"); System.out.println(); System.out.print("3+2=" +(3+2)); System.out.println(); } Job1(String mg) { msg=mg; } }

Comment: @KLCoder, Last time I suggested you place sample code formatted in your question. ;)

Comment: haha sure. I had no idea that comments will come like this. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use java.lang.System.nanoTime() to measure elapsed time - it's the most accurate timer available to you. It's an arbitrary counter though (it doesn't represent a time as such, it just counts nanoseconds), so you'll need to use it like this:

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime(); 

// do something

long t2 = System.nanoTime();

long elapsedTime = t2 - t1; // in nano-seconds, so remember to scale!
```

There's a good thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless) that goes into deep technical detail on the nanoTime call.

Comment: Actually I want the current time at which the thread starts not the elapsed time

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()       // Current moment in UTC
       .toString()  // Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-01-23T04:52:47.830065Z

For elapsed time:

```
Duration.between( instantThen , Instant.now() )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

While an `Instant` can represent a value in nanoseconds, it has limitations is *capturing* the current moment.

- In Java 8, the current moment is captured only up to milliseconds.
- In Java 9, a new [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) implementation now captures the current moment with a finer granularity.

In Java 9.0.1 on macOS Sierra, I am seeing current moments captured with microseconds.

> 2018-01-23T04:52:47.830065Z

To generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format seen above, simply call `toString()`.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString() ;
```

I suggest using the `Instant` in UTC with standard formatting for your logging needs. But if you insist otherwise, see the `DateTimeFormatter` & `ZonedDateTime` classes.

If you are calculating elapsed time, use `Duration` class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( instantThen , Instant.now() ) ;
```

To report, call `Duration::toString` to generate a String in [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).