# What's wrong with System.nanoTime?

Tags: java, performance, indexof, nanotime

I have a very long string with the pattern `</value>` at the very end, I am trying to test the performance of some function calls, so I made the following test to try to find out the answer... but I think I might be using nanoTime incorrectly? Because the result doesn't make sense no matter how I swap the order around...

```
  long start, end;

  start = System.nanoTime();
  StringUtils.indexOf(s, "</value>");
  end = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.println(end - start);

  start = System.nanoTime();
  s.indexOf("</value>");      
  end = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.println(end - start);

  start = System.nanoTime();
  sb.indexOf("</value>");
  end = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.println(end - start);
```

I get the following:

```
163566    // StringUtils
395227    // String
30797     // StringBuilder

165619    // StringBuilder
359639    // String
32850     // StringUtils
```

No matter which order I swap them around, the numbers will always be somewhat the same... What's the deal here?

From java.sun.com website's FAQ:

> Using System.nanoTime() between various points in the code to perform elapsed time measurements should always be accurate.

Also:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless

Comment: What happens if you do more runs in the same VM instance? Could you be seeing JIT optimisations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences between the two runs is in the order of microseconds and that is expected. There are many things going on on your machine which make the execution environment never the same between two runs of your application. That is why you get that difference.

**EDIT:** Java API says:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not **necessarily
>   nanosecond accuracy**.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there's memory initialization issues or other things that happen at the JVM's startup that is skewing your numbers.  You should get a bigger sample to get more accurate numbers.  Play around with the order, run it multiple times, etc.

Comment: Yes, I don't think measuring the calling time of one simple function is meaningful.  Calling System.nanoTime probably takes more time that the string functions themselves.  Maybe @codenamezero you could try running your example but completely removing the string functions; just measuring the time difference of nothing 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

It is more than likely that the methods you check use some common code behind the scenes. But the JIT will do its work only after about 10.000 invocations. Hence, this could be the cause why your first two example seem to be always slower.

Quick fix: just do the 3 method calls before the first measuring on a long enoug string.

Comment: all 3 of them use String.indexOf() behind the scenes

Comment: `s.indexOf("</value>");`
  
`s.indexOf("</value>");`
  
`s.indexOf("</value>");`
  
`StringUtils.indexOf(s, "</value>");`
  
`StringUtils.indexOf(s, "</value>");`
  
`StringUtils.indexOf(s, "</value>");`
  
`sb.indexOf("</value>");`
  
`sb.indexOf("</value>");`
  
`sb.indexOf("</value>");`

Freakin hell, can't paste anything useful using this reply crap...

30454
29086
27375