# Keeping Track of Time in a java program

Tags: java, time, linked-list

what I am trying to do is to have a process (this is just a object) with certiant values like:

```
public String name;
public int priority; //not to exceed 4
public int serviceTimeTotal; //holds the cumlitive service time
public int waitTimeTotal; //holds the cumulative wait time
public int arrivalTime;
public int burstTime;
public boolean added;
public boolean active;
public boolean isDone;
```

And I want to keep track of how much time each process gets service and how much time each process waits whle the other process gets service. I dont know if im keeping track of the time right or not I want the time in milliseconds and I think thats what it is in, im using the .nanoTime When I run the program it runs but the wait time does not increase at all but the service time for the one that is running does increase so I think I got that one right 
So here is how I am dong this

```
   public static void runLevelOne(LinkedList<MyProcess> ll, MyProcess mp)
{
    int start = 0;

    mp.active = true;
   System.out.println("Running Level One Queue");
    //runs for 3 millseconds
    while(start <= 3000)
    {
        //cheak to see if process is over
       if(mp.burstTime <= mp.serviceTimeTotal)
        {
            mp.isDone = true;
            System.out.println(mp.name + " has completed its task");
            mp.active = false;
            //get rid of it from the queue
            ll.remove(mp);
            break;

        }


        try {
            //run proccess
            Thread.sleep(3);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PartATwo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        start += System.nanoTime()/ 1000000;
        mp.serviceTimeCalculator(start);
        mp.calculatePriority();
        //make all other proccesses in ll wait
        for(MyProcess s :ll)
        {
            s.waiting(start);
            System.out.println(s.name+  " wait time: " + s.waitTimeTotal);
        }
        System.out.println(mp.name + " new priority is: " + mp.priority);
    }
    mp.active = false;

}
```

This runs the process and then calculates the service time, priority, and th wait time for each process in the linked list.

In the MyProcess class I calculate the priority like this

```
public int calculatePriority()
{
    System.out.println("Starting Priority " + priority);
    System.out.println("service time " + serviceTimeTotal);
    System.out.println("waitTimeTotal " + waitTimeTotal);

    priority = (serviceTimeTotal + waitTimeTotal) / serviceTimeTotal;
    if(priority <= 1.5)
    {
        priority = 1;
    }
    if(priority > 1.6 && priority <= 2.5 )
    {
        priority = 2;
    }
    if(priority > 2.6 && priority <= 3.5)
    {
        priority = 3;
    }
    if(priority > 3.6 && priority > 3.5)
    {
        priority = 4;
    }
    return priority;
}
```

and the service time and wait time like this

```
  public  void waiting(int time)
{
    if(active = false)
    {
        waitTimeTotal += time;
    }
}
 public void serviceTimeCalculator(int time)
{
    serviceTimeTotal += time;
}
```

This seams like it should work but it does not. am i missing something here
Thanks for any help with this

Comment: Beware: System.nanoTime() is not guaranteed to return values that increase over long periods of time. In my past use, subtracting end time from start time frequently resulted in negative numbers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use a `long` instead of an `int` to hold the time values, even if you divide them.

Then, you need to set the start time using `System.getNanos()` too, instead of setting it to `0`. Do something like:

```
long start = System.getNanos() / 1000000;
long end = start;
while (end - start < 3000) {
    ...
    end = System.getNanos() / 1000000;
}
```