# akka actor post a message to head of the MailBox

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Can a Producer actor post a message to another actor for immediate processing? i.e. post a message to the head of the Consumer MailBox instead of the tail of the Consumer MailBox?

I know that akka provides a way to configure my own defined Mailbox type, but how to control if some type of the messages need to be posted at the head of the MailBox instead of tail.
e.g. `TimerMessages`. i want a precise timer control for a time window implementation. messages must be kept for 1000 msec only (say), and if the message processing consumes time and there are many messages pending in the mailBox, i dont want timer Message to be appended to the same queue.

I could use a `PriorityMailBox`, but the trouble with `PriorityMailBox` is that even though it can put higher priority messages (timer messages) at the head of MailBox, for Messages of same priority, the order of messages in the MailBox is not guaranteed to be same as order of arrival. So i cannot use the priorityMailBox also.

Can someone please tell me how i can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your own `PriorityMailBox` which can take care of message's arrival time and use it as an additional priority (for messages with the same "main" priority).

Something like this (not tested):

```
import akka.dispatch._
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, PoisonPill, ActorSystem}
import java.util.Comparator
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue

class MyTimedPriorityMailbox(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, config: Config)
  extends UnboundedTimedPriorityMailbox(
    TimedPriorityGenerator {
      case 'highpriority ⇒ 0

      case 'lowpriority  ⇒ 2

      case PoisonPill    ⇒ 3

      case otherwise     ⇒ 1
    })

case class TimedEnvelope(envelope: Envelope) {
  private val _timestamp = System.nanoTime()
  def timestamp = _timestamp
}

class UnboundedTimedPriorityMailbox( final val cmp: Comparator[TimedEnvelope], final val initialCapacity: Int) extends MailboxType {
  def this(cmp: Comparator[TimedEnvelope]) = this(cmp, 11)
  final override def create(owner: Option[ActorRef], system: Option[ActorSystem]): MessageQueue =
    new PriorityBlockingQueue[TimedEnvelope](initialCapacity, cmp) with TimedQueueBasedMessageQueue with TimedUnboundedMessageQueueSemantics {
      override def queue: java.util.Queue[TimedEnvelope] = this
    }
}

trait TimedQueueBasedMessageQueue extends MessageQueue {
  def queue: java.util.Queue[TimedEnvelope]
  def numberOfMessages = queue.size
  def hasMessages = !queue.isEmpty
  def cleanUp(owner: ActorRef, deadLetters: MessageQueue) {
    if (hasMessages) {
      var envelope = dequeue()
      while (envelope ne null) {
        deadLetters.enqueue(owner, envelope)
        envelope = dequeue()
      }
    }
  }
}

trait TimedUnboundedMessageQueueSemantics extends TimedQueueBasedMessageQueue {
  def enqueue(receiver: ActorRef, handle: Envelope) { queue add TimedEnvelope(handle) }
  def dequeue(): Envelope = Option(queue.poll()).map(_.envelope).getOrElse(null)
}


object TimedPriorityGenerator {
  def apply(priorityFunction: Any ⇒ Int): TimedPriorityGenerator = new TimedPriorityGenerator {
    def gen(message: Any): Int = priorityFunction(message)
  }
}


abstract class TimedPriorityGenerator extends java.util.Comparator[TimedEnvelope] {
  def gen(message: Any): Int

  final def compare(thisMessage: TimedEnvelope, thatMessage: TimedEnvelope): Int = {
    val result = gen(thisMessage.envelope.message) - gen(thatMessage.envelope.message)
    // Int.MaxValue / Int.MinValue check omitted
    if(result == 0) (thisMessage.timestamp - thatMessage.timestamp).toInt else result
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, which akka version you have used for the example above? i am using akka 2.0.4, and i am getting some compilation errors. the method parameters for `UnboundedTimedPriorityMailbox.create` are `Option[ActorContext]` and method `cleanup(ActorContext,MessageQueue)` also needs to be defined. i have made changes to make it compile but i better use same akka version as yours.

Comment: I've used Akka 2.1.1 with Scala 2.10.0

Answer (score 2):

The code above works ok.

Only a detail. Avoid using System.getTimeNano(). It has problems in multi-core machines as it is defined by a per-cpu logic

[Here another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless)

Then, We have an strange behavior in the messages order Dependending on which cpu enque it.

I change it with classic System.currentTimeMillis(). It is less precise but, on our case if two messages with same priority and with same millisecond generation time, Don't care the order they are treated.

Thanks for the code!