# Calculating time difference with start time and elapsed time

Tags: java, android

```
public static final long TIMEOUT = 60000;
public static final long SYSTEM_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I have the TIMEOUT Value for my application set as 60000 and i have my system time. Now how would i know that `50 seconds` has been elapsed and i need to show a message to the end-user.

```
if (TIMEOUT  - SYSTEM_TIME <= 10000) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 Seconds Left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
}
```

Comment: use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: you can use Calendar as well

Comment: why not use nanoTime() for duration measurement? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless

Comment: postDelayed on a handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to do other stuff in that thread you can use a `sleep(50000)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to run a specific task one-shot:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {              
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO
                ...
            }
        }, TIMEOUT);
```

The doc is [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/Timer.html) (as reported by jimpanzer)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that you can use something like this :

```
long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
// do what you want
long endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
long ellapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
if (ellapsedTime>TIME_OUT) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am wrong or just not had enough coffee yet, but Timeout is 60000, your System value is much more - all millis starting at the year 1970 (if I am not mistaken here as well).  This means your result from TIMEOUT - SYSTEM_TIME is negative and therefor a negative number and therefor smaller than 10000.  So your if-statement always runs.