# Paradoxal timing functions

Tags: scala, scope, timing

I have a function to compute the time spent in a block:

```
import collection.mutable.{Map => MMap}
var timeTotalMap = MMap[String, Long]()
var numMap = MMap[String, Float]()
var averageMsMap = MMap[String, Float]()
def time[T](key: String)(block: =>T): T = {
  val start = System.nanoTime()
  val res = block
  val total = System.nanoTime - start
  timeTotalMap(key) = timeTotalMap.getOrElse(key, 0L) + total
  numMap(key) = numMap.getOrElse(key, 0f) + 1
  averageMsMap(key) = timeTotalMap(key)/1000000000f/numMap(key)
  res
}
```

I am timing a function and the place where it is called in one place.

```
time("outerpos") { intersectPos(a, b) }
```

and the function itself starts with:

```
def intersectPos(p1: SPosition, p2: SPosition)(implicit unify: Option[Identifier] =None): SPosition
    = time("innerpos") {(p1, p2) match {
   ...
}
```

When I display the nano times for each key (`timeTotalMap`), I get (added spaces for lisibility)

```
outerpos->  37 870 034 714
innerpos->      53 647 956
```

It means that the total execution time of innerpos is 1000 less than the one of outerpos.

What ! there is a factor 1000 between the two ? And its says that the outer call takes 1000x more time than all the inner functions? am I missing something or is there a memory leaking ghost somewhere ?

**Update**

When I compare the number of execution for each block (`numMap`), I find the following:

```
outerpos -> 362878
innerpos -> 21764
```

This is paradoxal. Even if `intersectPos` is called somewhere else, shouldn't the number of times it is called be as great as the number of times outerpos is called?

**EDIT**

If I move the line `numMap(key) = numMap.getOrElse(key, 0f) + 1` to the top of the time functinon, then these numbers become approximately equal.

Comment: are these nanos in results?

Comment: You can't perform timing in that manner and learn anything from it. This is a classic mistake of microbenchmarking on the JVM. You're measuring things like class loading times and JIT compilation (maybe, depending on lots of things). There's zillions of treatments of JVM microbenchmarking both within Stack Overflow and on the larger Web. There's no point recapitulating it again here.

Comment: @RandallSchulz good point about microbenchmarking

Comment: Even if the timing is wrong, the count itself of number of executions is also paradoxal. Can you find any explanation for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nanoTime` on JVM is considered safe but not very accurate. Here are some good reads:

[Is System.nanoTime() completely useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless)

[System.currentTimeMillis vs System.nanoTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime)

Basically your test will suffer from timer inaccuracy. One way to work around that would be to call `time("outerpos")` for a quite a long time (note JIT compiler optimization might kick in at some point) and measure start and end times only once. Take an average and repeat with `time("innerpos")`. That's all I could think of. Still not the best test ever ;)