# Java, sometimes I read a negative difference between two System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, timing

On a jogl [sample](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/tree/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/bindlessApp) of mine, I am having some performances [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083192/huge-performance-difference-jogl-vs-c).

I would like to profile it on the cpu side and I am using System.currentTimeMillis().

This is the main loop of my application:

```
    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable glad) {

    frameTimer.stop();

    frameDelta = frameTimer.getTime();

    // just an estimate
    totalTime += frameDelta;

    transformer.update(frameDelta);

    frameTimer.reset();

    GL4 gl4 = glad.getGL().getGL4();

    frameTimer.start();

    draw(gl4);

    checkGlError(gl4);

    glad.swapBuffers();
}
```

`frameDelta` is a [class](https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/blob/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/util/NvStopWatch.java) that has the following methods:

```
    private long startTime;
    private long diffTime;
    private boolean running;


    public NvStopWatch() {
        running = false;
    }

    /**
     * Start time measurement.
     */
    public void start() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        running = true;
    }

    /**
     * Stop time measurement.
     */
    public void stop() {
        diffTime = getDiffTime();
        running = false;
    }

    /**
     * Reset time counters to zero.
     */
    public void reset() {
        diffTime = 0;
        if (running) {
            start();
        }
    }

    public float getTime() {
        float ms = running ? getDiffTime() : diffTime;
        return ms / 1000;
    }

    /**
     * Get difference between start time and current time.
     *
     * @return
     */
    private long getDiffTime() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = now - startTime;
        if (diff < 0) {
            System.out.println("diff " + diff + " now " + now + " startTime " + startTime);
            diff = (long) BindlessApp.minimumFrameDeltaTime;
        }
        return diff;
    }
```

As you see the calling order of its methods is `.stop()`, `.getTime()`, `.reset()` and `.start()`

Sometimes, on the `.getTime()` it happens that a negative value is returned.. just randomly without any schema or something

How could it be possible?

Edit: 
I did some test on windows 7 x64 (without any `volatile`, `synchronized` and `nanoTime()`), I dont get any negative delta over there.. only on ubuntu 15.04 x64..

Anyway unfortunately on Ubuntu `volatile` and `synchronized` don't help, `nanoTime()` instead does.

Do you have a valid explanation to that? Something wrong with the java implementation? I am using the one of [webupd8team](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/), 8u45.

Comment: What is startTime declared as?

Comment: At a glance it looks like you might have threading issues.  Is the running variable declared as volatile?  Also anytime running is accessed I see a chance for inconsistency. You may want to synchronize the start() and stop() methods to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @John, as long (I edited the question)

Comment: @cyber-monk, no, then I will try to declare it as volatile and declare start() and stop() synchronized

Comment: @cyber-monk, not working, I got it again

Comment: Could be a background process that is updating your time on a regular basis. Could also consider [System.nanoTime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/510462/823393) as it will not drift backwards.

Comment: When does .start() get called?, seems like getDiffTime() assumes .start() has been called

Comment: @cyber-monk `.start()` gets called just before ` draw(gl4);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when a background task updates the time, perhaps in an attempt to correct it for drift.

You can rely on [System.nanoTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless) to not go backwards.

To quote [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

> The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative).