# Break from while loop after 20 seconds

Tags: java, if-statement, time, while-loop, jvm

How can I break from a while loop after 20 seconds have passed? I want to avoid the use of threads.

```
while (var) {
    // ...do something

    if (20secondsIsPassed) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The simple way is to use [`System.currentTimeMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) to test the system clock.

Comment: Take a time before entering and then in each iteration take a time difference if the time difference more than 20 seconds, exit the while loop.

Comment: I don't know, but I am pretty sure implementing a timer without threads is impossible. Search up Timer and Timertask, I don't think it is very complicated.

Comment: @StephenC Would not `System.nanoTime()` be more appropriate to time a duration?

Comment: Not unless the user needs (possibly) nanosecond resolution.   (Also, read the weasel words in the javadoc.)   But there are *many* solutions to this problem, with and without using threads explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: @StephenC I thought `currentTimeMillis` can return a value less than the previous invocation (maybe not likely, but possibly) depending on the underlying system clock which is why `nanoTime` should be used to measure a duration of time.

Comment: OK ... maybe.  However, neither `nanoTime()` or `currentTimeMillis()` is guaranteed by the javadoc to be monotically increasing.  So you are really relying on the operating system **in both cases**.

Comment: @StephenC Fair enough, though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510462/is-system-nanotime-completely-useless/54566928#54566928) indicates `nanoTime` is monotonic (though doesn't say _increasing_) since Java 7. Given it's supposed to use the same origin for all invocations in the same JVM, should it not be impossible for the time to _decrease_?

Comment: It should not be possible.  However, system clocks can be "adjusted".  And it is OS specific 1) whether adjustment is permitted for a given clock, and 2) whether an application will notice this.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/6344-time-is-an-illusion-lunchtime-doubly-so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `if` inside your `while` loop, that checks for time elapsed, then you won't have exactly 20 seconds, but **at least** 20s. The easiest way though is something like this:

```
LocalDateTime then = LocalDateTime.now();
while (true) {
    // logic
    if (ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(then, LocalDateTime.now()) >= 20) break;
}
```

Comment: That'll give you at least 21 seconds. Use >= instead and a more fine grained time unit.

Answer (score 4):

Simply by knowing that each second represent 1000 millisecond you can do the following calculation:

```
long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (var && (seconds + (20 * 1000) > System.currentTimeMillis())) {
        // ...do something
    }
```