# how to exit main function after executing for specific time in C

Tags: c

my program captures network traffic from the internet to analyse the packets for ambuiguity .I'm using winPcap library. Now I want the program to run for 2 mins & exit the program automatically without manually closing the command prompt console. Can you provide me the code to do this. 
thank you

code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    u_int i, res , inum ;
    u_char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE] , buffer[100];
    u_char *pkt_data;
    time_t seconds;
    struct tm tbreak;
    pcap_if_t *alldevs, *d;
    pcap_t *fp;
    struct pcap_pkthdr *header;

    fopen_s(&logfile , "log.txt" , "w");

    if(logfile == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Unable to create file.");
    }

    /* The user didn't provide a packet source: Retrieve the local device list */
    if (pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in pcap_findalldevs_ex: %s\n", errbuf);
        return -1;
    }

    i = 0;
    /* Print the list */
    for(d=alldevs; d; d=d->next)  
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n    ", ++i, d->name);

        if (d->description)
        {
            printf(" (%s)\n", d->description);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" (No description available)\n");
        }
    }

    if (i==0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"No interfaces found! Exiting.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter the interface number you would like to sniff : ");
    scanf_s("%d" , &inum);


    /* Jump to the selected adapter */
    for (d=alldevs, i=0; i< inum-1 ;d=d->next, i++);

    /* Open the device */
    if ( (fp= pcap_open(d->name,
                        100 /*snaplen*/,
                        PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS /*flags*/,
                        20 /*read timeout*/,
                        NULL /* remote authentication */,
                        errbuf)
                        ) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nError opening adapter\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //read packets in a loop :)
    while((res = pcap_next_ex( fp, &header, &pkt_data)) >= 0)
    {
        if(res == 0)
        {
            // Timeout elapsed
            continue;
        }
        seconds = header->ts.tv_sec;
        localtime_s( &tbreak , &seconds);
        strftime (buffer , 80 , "%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p" , &tbreak );
        //print pkt timestamp and pkt len
        //fprintf(logfile , "\nNext Packet : %ld:%ld (Packet Length : %ld bytes) " , header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec, header->len);
        fprintf(logfile , "\nNext Packet : %s.%ld (Packet Length : %ld bytes) " , buffer , header->ts.tv_usec, header->len);
        ProcessPacket(pkt_data , header->caplen);
    }

    if(res == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading the packets: %s\n" , pcap_geterr(fp) );
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to exit out of a loop after an elapsed time of 30ms in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946167/what-is-the-best-way-to-exit-out-of-a-loop-after-an-elapsed-time-of-30ms-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void exitfunc(int sig)
{
    _exit();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    signal(SIGALRM, exitfunc);
    alarm(120);

    return 0;
}
```

should work

Comment: I was suggested to add comments. But I think if you are using linux, you should know how to google "c signal function" and "c alarm function".

Comment: If it's POSIX `exit()` is **not** save to be called from a signal handler. However `_exit()` is (see `man 7 signal`).

Comment: As I wrote: `man 7 signal`, at least on my Linux (Debian stable).

Comment: Ok, to be exact POSIX does **not** list `exit()` "*as guaranteed to be called savely from a signal handler*".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25664/discussion-between-dmitry-and-alk)