# Run multiple commands in c

Tags: c

I want to create a program. That, someone, must find the hidden number, but also I want to put a timer but I don't how can I make those run simultaneously. Here is my code

```
enter code here







#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void timer();
int main(void) {

  timer();
  return 0;
}void timer(){
  int i=0;
  int b= 61;
  for( i=0;i<b;i++){
    sleep(1);

  printf("\n%d",i);
  }
   int hidden,x;
  srand(time(NULL));
  hidden=1+rand()%100;
  do{
    printf("\nGuess the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(x==hidden)
    printf("\nYou found the hidden number");
    else if(x>hidden)
    printf("\nPut a smaller number");
    else
    printf("\nPut a larger number");
  }while(x!=hidden);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226603/timeout-function)

Comment: Here is another one: [Implementing execution timeout with C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896388/implementing-execution-timeout-with-c-c). And so on if you search for "timeout in C".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **C signal function** and the **C alarm function**. As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241013/how-to-exit-main-function-after-executing-for-specific-time-in-c/15241050)

You should also find an alternative to scanf, as it provides no protection for arithmetic overflow. You could use fgets instead.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void terminate(int signal)
{
   exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
   int snum = 0, num = 0;

   srand(time(NULL));
   snum = rand() % 10 + 1;

   puts("Try to guess the number within 10 seconds!");
   signal(SIGALRM, terminate);
   alarm(10);

   if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
   {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

      while (num != snum)
      {
         puts("Your guess is wrong!");
   
         if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
         {
            fprintf(stderr, "Guess is probably not a number\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
      }
   puts("Congratulations!");

   return 0;
}
```