# System.nanoTime() equivalent in C

Tags: java, c, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Timer function to provide time in nano seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds)

I need to get out of a loop when approaching 3 seconds, so I need to calculate the elapsed time.

I'm moving some code from Java to C, and I was using the easy System.nanoTime() in Java,

How would I do that in C?

I noticed that time(NULL) will return the seconds, but I'm looking for more precision.

Thank you in advance

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds

Answer (score 1):

For the resolution you want, `clock()` from the C standard library is sufficient:

```
#include <time.h>
#define RUNTIME_MAX_SEC 3

clock_t start = clock();
while(clock() - start < CLOCKS_PER_SEC * RUNTIME_MAX_SEC)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

use [gettimeofday](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/gettimeofday.html) , it has microseconds resolution. System.nanoTime() in Java is commonly implemented using gettimeofday on *nixes

Comment: Caution; gettimeofday may reports a value in microseconds, but the actual resolution is platform dependent. It is not updated at that rate.