# timestamp in c with milliseconds precision

Tags: c, windows, datetime, time.h

I'm relatively new to C programming and I'm working on a project which needs to be very time accurate; therefore I tried to write something to create a timestamp with milliseconds precision.

It seems to work but my question is whether this way is the right way, or is there a much easier way? Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    while(1) if(clock() - start >= milliseconds) break;
}

int main()
{
    time_t now;
    clock_t milli;
    int waitMillSec = 2800, seconds, milliseconds = 0;
    struct tm * ptm;

    now = time(NULL);
    ptm = gmtime ( &now );
    printf("time before: %d:%d:%d:%d\n",ptm->tm_hour,ptm->tm_min,ptm->tm_sec, milliseconds );

    /* wait until next full second */
    while(now == time(NULL));

    milli = clock();
    /* DO SOMETHING HERE */
    /* for testing wait a user define period */
    wait(waitMillSec);
    milli = clock() - milli;

    /*create timestamp with milliseconds precision */
    seconds = milli/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    milliseconds = milli%CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    now = now + seconds;
    ptm = gmtime( &now );
    printf("time after: %d:%d:%d:%d\n",ptm->tm_hour,ptm->tm_min,ptm->tm_sec, milliseconds );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code seems likely to provide millisecond granularity:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    SYSTEMTIME t;
    GetSystemTime(&t); // or GetLocalTime(&t)
    printf("The system time is: %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d\n", 
        t.wHour, t.wMinute, t.wSecond, t.wMilliseconds);
    return 0;
}
```

This is based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. The above code snippet was tested with CYGWIN on Windows 7.

For Windows 8, there is [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which "retrieves the current system date and time with the highest possible level of precision (<1us)."

Your original approach would probably be ok 99.99% of the time (ignoring one minor bug, described below).  Your approach is:

- Wait for the next second to start, by repeatedly calling `time()` until the value changes.
- Save that value from `time()`.
- Save the value from `clock()`.
- Calculate all subsequent times using the current value of `clock()` and the two saved values.

Your minor bug was that you had the first two steps reversed.

But even with this fixed, this is not guaranteed to work 100%, because there is no atomicity. Two problems:

- Your code loops `time()` until you are into the next second. But how *far* are you into it? It could be 1/2 a second, or even several seconds (e.g. if you are running a debugger with a breakpoint).
- Then you call `clock()`. But this saved value has to 'match' the saved value of `time()`. *If* these two calls are almost instantaneous, as they *usually* are, then this is fine. But Windows (and Linux) time-slice, and so there is no guarantee.

Another issue is the granularity of `clock`. If CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1000, as seems to be the case on your system, then of course the best you can do is 1 msec. But it can be worse than that: on Unix systems it is typically 15 msecs. You could improve this by replacing `clock` with `QueryPerformanceCounter(),` as in the answer to [timespec equivalent for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583308/timespec-equivalent-for-windows), but this may be otiose, given the first two problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response. I will try this when im back at my working machine. Until now I didn't dare to use any windows headers. Unfortunately I have to use Windows xp and Visual Studio 6.0, hopefully this wont be a problem.

Comment: @morten: The msdn link says `GetSystemTime` is available on Windows 2000 and up, and I have just verified that it seems to work on my XP Home SP3 machine. Good luck, and tell us what you end up doing.

Comment: just wanted to  say thank you i just implemented your idea and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

Clock periods are not at all guaranteed to be in milliseconds. You need to explicitly convert the output of clock() to milliseconds.

```
t1 = clock();
// do something
t2 = clock();
long millis = (t2 - t1) * (1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, why don't you just use [Sleep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Sadly I didn't knew of it. As I said, Im quite new to c programming and it took me rather long to come up with a waiting function :)

Comment: @morten - Busy loops unnecessarily consume a lot of CPU.  Non-zero Sleep() gives up the current process' time slice back to the kernel so that it can schedule another process to run.