# clock_t difference in 6 decimal positions

Tags: c

I use this code for measuring computing time of my C program:

```
clock_t start = clock() ;
do_some_work() ;
clock_t end = clock() ;
double elapsed_time = (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
```

Problem is, that this double elapsed_time returns only number with 2 decimal positions, like 1,78 seconds, but I want to enlarge it to 6 decimal positions. Is there any way how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code where you print the value, you've most likely just have a format problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds)