# timer in c that do not exhaust cpu

Tags: c, timer

I wrote a timer following some examples from the web:

```
void fun(int i)
{
    struct itimerval to;

//do something

    signal(SIGALRM, fun);

    to.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    to.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    to.it_value.tv_sec = 60;
    to.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &to, 0);
}
```

in the main function, I just call this fun once and then do a while loop there.

The program behave well except that it exhaust the cpu fully (by 99% or 100%), but if I remove the while loop, the "fun" function is called just once. How could I keep it being called periodically while avoid occupy the cpu for 100%?

Comment: You expect this to call fun once every 60 seconds?

Comment: Your problem is most likely in your `while` loop. Post the full code that's necessary to describe the situation.

Comment: The function itself is fine. Show us your main!

Comment: in the main function, I just call this fun once and then do a while loop there: int main() { fun(0); while(1);}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), so that your program sleeps and consumes no CPU when there is nothing to do. An easy way would be to use [libevent](http://libevent.org/).

Otherwise, use [`select()` or `pselect()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803715/how-to-make-a-thread-sleep-block-for-nanoseconds-or-at-least-milliseconds/5804151#5804151).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pause()`. [link](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Using-Pause.html#Using-Pause)

in the main :

```
fun(i);
while(1)
    pause();
```

and `fun()` will execute fun every 60 seconds.

`sleep()` or `Sleep()` (windows) is also your friend. (in the loop instead of pause())

another way is to use `sigsuspend()` [link](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Sigsuspend.html#Sigsuspend)

Answer (score 0):

select() in C would do what you want. And it is of microsecond granularity.