# Fast time function C/C++

Tags: c++, c, performance, time

I am currently using time from the ctime library. Is there any faster alternative?

```
time_t start_time, elapsed_time;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    start_time = time(NULL);
    /// optimized code
    if(condition_met())
    {
       elapsed_time = time(NULL) - start_time;
    } else continue;
}
```

time(NULL) just isn't fast enough.

Comment: How did you determine `time` isn't fast enough ?

Comment: Not in the standard library. Specific systems have specific ways to measure execution time, you need to specify what system/OS the code is intended for.

Comment: I am looking for a faster alternative. It is not enough because it introduces an overhead(the method in which it is being used is called roughly 10mil times per second)

Comment: I am currently on a windows(32bit) box.

Comment: Why would you call it so often? What are you trying to do? Probably there is a better approach.

Comment: By 'fast', are you talking about the resolution? Are you always getting 0 for `elapsed_time`.

Comment: On Linux x64, `gettimeofday` is a virtual syscall which is pretty fast.

Comment: It is a network generator. It generates networks based on a certain topology and then tries simulating traffic in a cluster. I'm using that function in order to determine a very basic performance metric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to want to only measure elapsed time (and aren't concerned with the absolute time). One of the fastest approaches of measuring elapsed time (if you are on x86) is to read the [rdtsc counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter). In mvsc++ this can be achieved by:

```
#include <intrin.h>
unsigned __int64 rdtsc(void)
{
    return __rdtsc();
}
```

Comment: Do note the caveats of using this method on multi-core/hyperthreaded systems as described in the linked wikipedia entry. For Windows systems the [recommended alternative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417693%28VS.85%29.aspx) is to use `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

Comment: But would you care to explain on how to use this to measure elapsed time ?

Comment: One could also affinitize the thread using RDTSC to a specific CPU.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I'm guessing that, given that it counts whole seconds, what you may be saying is that `time(NULL)` is not *granular* enough. In other words, you *may* be wanting to go down to milli, micro or nano seconds.

If that's the case take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds)