# How to get elapsed time in seconds from boost::timer::cpu_timer?

Tags: c++, boost

The following rough code, based on [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html), gives me the elapsed time in seconds from the timer object provided in boost.

```
boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;
// ...do some work...
const boost::timer::nanosecond_type oneSecond(1000000000LL);
return timer.elapsed().user / oneSecond;
```

The problem with this method is that I have this uncomfortable magic number in my code. Is there some method within boost that can give me *elapsed seconds* out of the **nanosecond_type** value available from the call to **elapsed().user**, without having this magic number sitting in my code?

**(EDIT:) Conclusion:**

Based on the accepted answer, I ended up with this snippet in my production code:

```
boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;
// ...do some work...
auto nanoseconds = boost::chrono::nanoseconds(timer.elapsed().user + timer.elapsed().system);
auto seconds = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::seconds>(nanoseconds);
std::cout << seconds.count() << std::endl;
```

Comment: My first guess would be that `duration_cast` from `boost::chrono` can do this -- assuming that `chrono` and `timer` are compatible in this respect.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd feel uncomfortable about the magic number, as duration_cast simply pushes the magic down into boost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @jogojapan suggested, [boost::chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/chrono.html) would be a good choice. But you don't need the duration_cast<> if you use `double` as underlying type.

```
typedef boost::chrono::duration<double> sec; // seconds, stored with a double
sec seconds = boost::chrono::nanoseconds(timer.elapsed().user);
std::cout << seconds.count() << "s\n"; // gives the number of seconds, as double.
```

Comment: based on your advice I wrote [some code](http://pastebin.com/gLva8zqU). I kept the duration_cast that @jogojapan suggested because it felt more readable. Testing now.

Comment: I think the problem with this is that it cuts of the decimal part...?

Answer (score 1):

One more addition:

```
double
getSeconds( const boost::timer::nanosecond_type& elapsed )
{
  return
    static_cast< double >(
      boost::chrono::nanoseconds( elapsed ).count()
    ) * boost::chrono::nanoseconds::period::num / boost::chrono::nanoseconds::period::den;
}
```

This you can call with `timer.elapsed().user` for example to get a double value of the elapsed time. This can obviously also transformed to `std::chrono`, if wanted / supported.

Answer (score 0):

You should measure the number of tick per nanosecond on each Hardware your soft run..
take a look at (
[Timer function to provide time in nano seconds using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds))

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, I'm specifically trying to use the class *boost::timer::cpu_timer*.

Answer (score 0):

The boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer can be useful:

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;

  for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    std::sqrt(123.456L); // burn some time

  return 0;
}
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html