# How to call a method/function 50 time in a second

Tags: c++, c, unix, time, timer

How to call a method/function 50 time in a second then calculate time spent, If time spent is less than one second then sleep for (1-timespent) seconds.

Below is the pseudo code

```
while(1)
{
  start_time = //find current time
  int msg_count=0;
  send_msg();
  msg_count++;

  // Check time after sending 50 messages
  if(msg_count%50 == 0)
  {
   curr_time = //Find current time
   int timeSpent = curr_time - start_time ;
   int waitingTime;

   start_time = curr_time ;

   waitingTime = if(start_time < 1 sec) ? (1 sec - timeSpent) : 0;
   wait for waitingTime; 
  }
}
```

I am new with Timer APIs. Can anyone help me that what are the timer APIs, I have to use to achieve this. I want portable code.

Comment: How precise do you want to be? Are you sure that your processing (`send_msg` notably, which perhaps might block) is always taking much less than 20 milliseconds, i.e. the period for 50Hz ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Timer function to provide time in nano seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275004/c-timer-function-to-provide-time-in-nano-seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read the [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) man page.

Then you may want to call [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) to set up a timer. To query about time, use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

You probably may want to wait and multiplex on some input and output. [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) is useful for this. To sleep for a small amount of time without using the CPU consider [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html)

If using timer doing signals, read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and be careful because signal handlers are restricted to *async-signal-safe functions* (consider having a signal handler which just sets some global `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag). You may also be interested by the Linux specific [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) (which you could `poll` or pass to your event loop).

You might want to use some existing [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) library, like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) (or those from GTK/Glib, Qt, etc...), which are often using `poll` (or fancier things). The linux specific [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) and [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) might be very helpful.

[Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) is also useful to read.

If `send_msg` is doing network I/O, you probably need to redesign your program around some event loop (perhaps your own, based on `poll`) - you'll need to multiplex (i.e. `poll`) both on network sends and network recieves. [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) is then a useful paradigm.