# c++ code execution timer returning 0, need output in milliseconds

Tags: c++, time, execution

I'm trying to figure out how to time the execution of part of my program, but when I use the following code, all I ever get back is 0. I know that can't be right. The code I'm timing recursively implements mergesort of a large array of ints. How do I get the time it takes to execute the program in milliseconds?

```
//opening input file and storing contents into array
index = inputFileFunction(inputArray);

clock_t time = clock();//start the clock

//this is what needs to be timed
newRecursive.mergeSort(inputArray, 0, index - 1);

//getting the difference        
time = clock() - time;

double ms = double(time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000;

std::cout << "\nTime took to execute: " << std::setprecision(9) << ms << std::endl;
```

Comment: `clock()` only has second precision (and on a 32bit system it can wrap every 36 minutes), so if `mergeSort()` takes less than 1 second to run, that would explain why you get a result of 0. For what you are attempting, you need to use a higher-precision timer, such as from `clock_gettime()`, or even an OS-specific API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the chrono library in C++11. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
#include <chrono>
//...
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
// do whatever you're timing
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto durationMS = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
std::cout << "\n Time took " << durationMS.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Sorry in the last line of cout you need durationMS.count() instead of durationMS

Comment: thank your for your help. when i implemented your code though it's still giving me an output of 0 :(

Comment: Do you think it's running in less than 1 microsecond? Maybe try `nanoseconds` instead of microseconds in `duration_cast`?

Comment: @grigor I think you're right. I increased the size of the data that the recursive mergesort has to go through so it takes longer, and something other than 0 finally showed up. Is there anything smaller than nanoseconds?

Comment: @drescherjm Initially I was sorting through an array of 1000 ints, which yielded a result of 0. I had to bump up the array size to 45,000 to get something other than 0.

Comment: Ok glad it worked. I don't think there is anything smaller than nanoseconds. A cpu cycle takes roughly a nanosecond, so you can't really time anything less than that.

Comment: Rarely will you have a clock that can resolve to nanoseconds. C++ allows you to specify nanoseconds because why not? Costs almost nothing and you don't have to rewrite that part of the standard later.

Comment: Re: Smaller than nanoseconds:  You can create your own picoseconds if you want:  `using picoseconds = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::pico>;`.  That won't make your clock more accurate.  But it can come in handy when averaging: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11485388/576911

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on OSX, this [blog post](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html) from Apple may be useful. It contains code snippets that should give you the timing resolution you need.