# Is there an equivalent instruction to rdtsc in ARM?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

For my project **I must use inline assembly instructions** such as **rdtsc** to calculate the execution time of some C/C++ instructions.

The following code seems to work on Intel but not on ARM processors:

```
{unsigned a, d;asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d)); t0 = ((unsigned long)a) | (((unsigned long)d) << 32);}
//The C++ statement to measure its execution time
{unsigned a, d;asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d)); t1 = ((unsigned long)a) | (((unsigned long)d) << 32);}
time = t1-t0;
```

**My question is:**

How to write an **inline assembly code similar to the above** (to calculate the execution elapsed time of an instruction) to work on ARM processors?

Comment: `rdtsc` on multi-core processors can have issues. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417693(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Single instructions will have variable timings based on cache etc. Better to loop thousands of times over it/them and use the perf_events() common functionality to make it work on all supported CPUs.

Comment: @RichardCritten `rdtsc()` is very reliable on all modern CPUs. Even on multisocket systems, that have a few years old CPUs, I get nearly identical values for `rdtsc()` over all the cores. Only very old systems, that don't have `constant_tsc` and `nonstop_tsc()` in their capabilities, have those issues mentioned in the microsoft document.

Comment: @KaiPetzke did you check the date of my comment ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, I did check the date. But in particular, because that linked Microsoft document is still available and was not updated, I found it necessary to comment, that this is now a problem of the past.

Answer (score 22):

You should read the `PMCCNTR` register of a co-processor `p15` (not an actual co-processor, just an entry point for CPU functions) to obtain a cycle count. Note that it is available to an unprivileged app only if:

1. Unprivileged `PMCCNTR` reads are alowed:

   Bit 0 of `PMUSERENR` register must be set to 1 ([official docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0460c/Bgbhfegi.html))
2. `PMCCNTR` is actually counting cycles:

   Bit 31 of `PMCNTENSET` register must be set to 1 ([official docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0460c/Bgbejcgj.html))

This is [a real-world example](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/v1.1.0/src/cycleclock.h#L116) of how it`s done.

Comment: @Curious Note that the answer above is valid for ARMv6 and above. Older arch versions might have their own methods of getting this data (specific to a partcular chip - so the info is to be found in the datasheet for the chip), while some ARM-based chips don't provide such data at all.

Comment: **My ARM CPU is ARM7A**, confirmed that by using the compiler Macro__ARM_ARCH_7A__, however, when I try to use the instruction asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, **%0**, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr));, the compiler gives the error message: Error “no such instruction” asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, **%eax**, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr));

Comment: **My Build Environment=** PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.3
TARGET_PRODUCT=full_manta
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a15
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.16.0-70-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=JWR66V
OUT_DIR=out

Comment: @hidefromkgb: This is the code that I used but it gives the above error. 
    {uint32_t pmccntr;asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr));t0=static_cast<int64_t>(pmccntr) * 64;}
 //The C++ statement to measure its execution time
{uint32_t pmccntr;asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr));t1=static_cast<int64_t>(pmccntr) * 64;}
time = t1-t0;

Comment: @Curious You are, most probably, using the wrong binutils, since `as` is definitely trying to assemble X86 instead of ARM7A. And, BTW, `* 64` is equivalent to `<< 6`, and the result does not have to be either promoted to `uint64_t` or multiplied until (T1 – T0) is calculated. As the difference is typically way smaller than 2²⁶, multiplying it to 64 won\`t require promotion to a 64-bit type.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: I followed the [AOSP guidelines](https://source.android.com/source/building.html) and I did not change anything in the binutils. How to force the `as` to assemble ARM7A instead of X86?

Comment: @Curious AOSP is by itself useless in your case: it does not allow anything but Java as a language in which apps can be written. And that\`s for a good reason, as there are many different hardware architectures that support Android, so compiling machine code for all of them is a pain — and still you\`d leave out those which aren\`t yet supported. What you really need is [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html). NDK is positioned as a last-resort kit intended for programmers who positively do know what they are doing.

Comment: The URL provided is really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

For Arm64, the system register `CNTVCT_EL0` can be used to retrieve the counter from
user space.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
u64 rdtsc(void)
{
    u64 val;

    /*
     * According to ARM DDI 0487F.c, from Armv8.0 to Armv8.5 inclusive, the
     * system counter is at least 56 bits wide; from Armv8.6, the counter
     * must be 64 bits wide.  So the system counter could be less than 64
     * bits wide and it is attributed with the flag 'cap_user_time_short'
     * is true.
     */
    asm volatile("mrs %0, cntvct_el0" : "=r" (val));

    return val;
}
```

Please refer this patch https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/1305380/ for more details.

Comment: Do you think it's appropriate to relicense that GPL 2.0 code from the Linux kernel as CC BY-SA by posting it on StackOverflow?

Comment: @JeffHammond Thank you for point it. I added the GPL 2.0 license.

Comment: @JeffHammond: can you put a license on a sequence of two assembler instructions?

Comment: Does the GPL include a minimum number of things that are copied before it applies?

Comment: I tried this code, but it didn't work for me. It doesn't make sense that a sequence of code with 2304 multiplications execute in 30 cycles.

Comment: It is not working for me either. I tried to approximate the CPU frequency in a 2 GHz aarch64 processor. `s = rdtsc(); sleep(1); e = rdtsc(); freq = (double)(e - s) / 10e9`. This code is reporting 20 MHz.

Comment: `CNTVCT_EL0`, `CNTPCT_EL0` and friends aren't CPU cycle counters like x86 `rdtsc` is.  Instead, they tick at some implementation-defined constant frequency which can be read from `CNTFRQ_EL0`.  The ARM docs say the frequency is typically between 1 and 50 MHz.  The good thing is they can be used for timing even when the CPU clock frequency may vary due to power saving modes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found a NON-GPL, but BSD source about reading the system's real time counter on ARM64 here: https://github.com/cloudius-systems/osv/blob/master/arch/aarch64/arm-clock.cc

Even better, the code there doesn't only deliver some sort of ticks as `rdtsc()` does on Intel/AMD, it even reports the frequency of those ticks. And yes, it's in sync on all cores on multicores. So it can be useful for many things, including benchmarking or keeping track of the threads in a thread pool etc. Of course, it won't have the long term stability of a system clock, that is synced to an external time source via `ntp`.

The `class arm_clock` defined in the cited code might be overkill for many purposes. It for example also shows how to set hardware timers, which is something, that a normal user mode process likely won't have the permissions to do. Here is an excerpt of the most important parts to just read TSC and frequencies. It compiles fine with recent GCC on Intel, AMD and ARM. Of course, the frequency reading is provided only on ARM:

```
#ifdef __ARM_ARCH_ISA_A64
// Adapted from: https://github.com/cloudius-systems/osv/blob/master/arch/aarch64/arm-clock.cc
uint64_t rdtsc() {
    //Please note we read CNTVCT cpu system register which provides
    //the accross-system consistent value of the virtual system counter.
    uint64_t cntvct;
    asm volatile ("mrs %0, cntvct_el0; " : "=r"(cntvct) :: "memory");
    return cntvct;
}

uint64_t rdtsc_barrier() {
    uint64_t cntvct;
    asm volatile ("isb; mrs %0, cntvct_el0; isb; " : "=r"(cntvct) :: "memory");
    return cntvct;
}

uint32_t rdtsc_freq() {
    uint32_t freq_hz;
    asm volatile ("mrs %0, cntfrq_el0; isb; " : "=r"(freq_hz) :: "memory");
    return freq_hz;
}
#else
#include <x86intrin.h>
uint64_t rdtsc(){ return __rdtsc(); }
#endif
```

Execution times tested by me were in the range of 7 ns for `rdtsc()` and 30 ns for `rdtsc_barrier()`, which are quite similar to Intel and AMD.