# Getting almost random time stamp counter on ARM

Tags: macos, assembly, arm

I'm trying to figure out how to access the TSC on ARM, i.e similar to using RDTSC on x86. There are multiple examples on SO, but none of them seem to do what I wanted. I copy pasted the following code from another question:

```
uint64_t ReadTSC() {
    uint64_t tsc;
    asm volatile("isb; mrs %0, PMCCNTR_EL0" : "=r" (tsc));
    return tsc;
}
```

I then tried the following code:

```
int main() {
  uint64_t before = ReadTSC();
  std::cout << "foo\n";
  uint64_t after = ReadTSC();
  std::cout << "Print took: " << after - before << std::endl;
}
```

However, the value I get is `18446744069338982144` for how long the print took. This seems completely nonsensical. The CPU I'm using is an Apple M2. What is the issue here?

What I'd like to measure is the actual precise number of clock cycles, i.e. avoid having to do conversions from wallclock time.

Comment: Apple's assembler uses `;` as a comment character, incompatibly with gas/clang on other platforms where it separates instructions as you were expecting.  So your asm is just doing `isb` and nothing else, and you are seeing whatever garbage value happened to be in the output register.  However, after fixing this (e.g. use `\n` instead), on my M1 it just crashes with SIGILL.

Comment: The PMU extension is optional in the ARMv8 architecture and I'm not sure whether Apple implements it.  I didn't see any indication of it in the `hw.*` sysctls, which is where other CPU features are reported. If it is implemented, it can also be blocked by the OS, so you may have to set up your program with special permissions in order to be allowed to use it.  I'm not sure how that would be done; simply running as `sudo` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You're right... checked the assembly that it generates and the MRS is missing. If I remove the "isb", then I get invalid instruction. Do you have any idea if there's some alternative on the M chips that can be used as a replacement for RDTSC?

Comment: There's some discussion of rdtsc on ARM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40454157/2189500).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: The first thing I actually tried based on ARM docs was CNTVCT_EL0. I noticed that on my M2 core it returns a 24Mhz tick, so it's not returning clock cycles. Seems like that discussion reaches the same conclusion without finding anything that matches RDTSC.

Comment: I found some sites that say Apple doesn't support the ARM PMUv3 performance counters such as `PMCCNTR_EL0`, but has their own (undocumented of course).  There is some code available to read them, but it needs a system call.  Apparently the supported way to use them is via the `Instruments` app in Xcode.  I don't have the links handy, but can try to come back and post them sometime if you don't find them.

Comment: Yeah, the answers linked by David unfortunately mix up `PMCCNTR_EL0` which is a genuine clock cycle counter (good for timing instructions, microarchitecture research, etc), with `CNTVCT_EL0` which just counts at an arbitrary fixed frequency in the 10 MHz range (good for high-resolution timing in general).  Of course, on x86 people use `RDTSC` for both purposes (poorly) so I can understand why the confusion arises.