Why only the first time CNTVCT_EL0 is returned?
So it's a follow-up to this answer. I simply created a terminal app with Xcode and basically pasted the code there but in a loop:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

uint64_t getfreq(void) {
    uint64_t value=0;
    asm("isb; mrs %0, CNTVCT_EL0" : "=r"(value));
    return value;
}

int main() {
    do {
        printf("CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x%016llX\n", getfreq());
    } while(1);
}

Issue I have is I get something like this as output:
CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x0000000104CB1910
CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x0000000000000001
CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x0000000000000001
CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x0000000000000001

Why is only the first time the value looks remotely valid (it's the same if I don't have a loop) - maybe I need to clear something with another asm instruction?
Xcode Version 15.4 (15F31d)
MacOS 14.5 (23F79)
Mac mini m1 (2020)

Out of curiosity, have you tried adding in another ISB after the MRS?

@ThomasJager Well no but I tried the original post I've found while searching for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67968296 and it works (the initial value here seems not to be correct also).

Voting to close as typo. ; starts a comment in assembly, so the entire mrs is never emitted. The value you've been reading (x8) was just uninitialised the first time round, and subsequently the constant 1 that was used for the loop condition because you compiled without optimisations. Use \n for multiple instructions in asm.

@siguza: In arm assembly, anyway. X86 gas lets you use ; to separate instructions, but indeed arm does not.

@NateEldredge I guess that makes sense ok thanks.
