# CPU cycle count c++

Tags: c++, optimization, inline-assembly, cpu-cycles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting cpu cycles using RDTSC - why does the value of RDTSC always increase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602336/getting-cpu-cycles-using-rdtsc-why-does-the-value-of-rdtsc-always-increase)
>   [Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/get-cpu-cycle-count)

I want to write C++ code which analyzes sorting algorithms, and I need to know how many processor cycles it takes to sort an array.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/get-cpu-cycle-count):

```
uint64_t rdtsc(){
    unsigned int lo,hi;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
    return ((uint64_t)hi << 32) | lo;
}
```

I understand it is inline assembly, could someone explain how it works and how to use it?

I run Linux. My computer is dual core, does that makes a difference?

Comment: Why not just measure the wall time like any normal person would do?

Comment: If you're using rdtsc, you're not "analyzing" sorting algorithms, you're empirically measuring the performance of specific implementations of those algorithms.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Not sure what "normal" person you're talking about; I think a lot of programmers concerned about performance use rdtsc or similar.

Comment: Please read the answer to [Getting cpu cycles using RDTSC - why does the value of RDTSC always increase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602336/getting-cpu-cycles-using-rdtsc-why-does-the-value-of-rdtsc-always-increase). Also, note rdtsc always assumes you are running on the same processor.

Comment: Jasse's Good's comment solved the case, thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the call `clock`?

It is [documented here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/), and seems to be what you want.

Comment: Fix me if i'm wrong. Basicly why i whant cpu cycles because it's constant, and clock readings depends on situation.

Comment: From the documentation:  "Returns the processor time **consumed by the program.**"  *(ie: not CPU-wide, just specific to that one program)*

Comment: nice, this changes everything.