# linux driver rdtsc implicit declaration

Tags: linux, driver

I wrote a linux driver module (which is on x86_64), I just call rdtsc, but compiler printed:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'rdtsc'
```

Which header file should I include?

Comment: `__rdtsc()` from `immintrin.h` will inline to `rdtsc`, so you can use that ([Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907627)).  Or see the inline asm in mysticial's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Wrong uses of RDTSC

First I saw that you had used the "time" tag for your question. RDTSC is not a good thing to use for time.  See [Getting cpu cycles using RDTSC - why does the value of RDTSC always increase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602336/getting-cpu-cycles-using-rdtsc-why-does-the-value-of-rdtsc-always-increase)

for an excellent explanation.

## Answer

However if you DO want to use RDTSC functions, the are intel x86 architecture specific and its prototypes are found in `linux-source/arch/asm/msr.h`