# View executed time of bash script in nanoseconds

Tags: bash

Currently, the time $0 command within my bash script shows the following similar output

```
time $0

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

but ideally, I would like to see the execution time of the script in nanoseconds. How would this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you won't get reliable measurements with this precision.

[Worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586354/linux-time-command-microseconds-or-better-accuracy)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked

```
start_time="$(date -u +%N)"
end_time="$(date -u +%N)"
nanotime="$(bc <<<"$end_time-$start_time")"
echo "$nanotime"
```